# Symmetric difference between countably many set: does $\bigcup A_i^c\cap \bigcup A_i=\bigcup A_i\cap A_{i+1}^c$ hold?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This might be a trivial question but I am having a hard time trying to figure it out.

Let be $A$ and $B$ two subsets then I can write the symmetric difference  as
$$A\Delta B=(A\backslash B)\cup(B\backslash A)=(A^c\cup B^c)\cap(A\cup B).$$

I am wondering if I have countably many sets $A_i$ 
, $i\in \mathbb N$ I can write:

$$\bigcup A_i^c\cap \bigcup A_i=\bigcup A_i\cap A_{i+1}^c$$

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: One counterexample has been given in the answers if we allow the sets to be the empty set. What if we assume that the sets are nonempty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sequence $\emptyset, X,X,...$. Then the right side is empty but the left side is $X$.

For the edited question just replace the first set in this example by $\{0\}$.

Comment: I don't get your point, if $A_i=A$ and $A_{i+1}=A^c$ then $A_i\cap A_{i+1}^c=A\cap (A^c)^c\neq \emptyset$, why should the union be empty on the right side?

Comment: @RScrlli I have edited my answer.

Comment: That's a valid point, would the equality hold if I assume that the sets are nonempty?

Comment: @RScrlli No. On RHS you have to all sets of the type $A_i\cap A_j^{c}$ for the identity to hold. Taking  just $i$ and $i+1$ will not give anything like LHS.